# Find all non-trivial congruence relations on $(\mathbb{Z},+,0,-)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

First of all, I have already proven that for every $d\in\mathbb{N}$ the relation

\begin{align*}
a\sim_d b:\Leftrightarrow\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}:\,b-a=kd
\end{align*}

is a congruence relation on $(\mathbb{Z},+,0,-)$. Furthermore, the trivial ones $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ as well as ${\rm id}_\mathbb{Z}$ are congruence relations.

Are those all of them and how do I prove it?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by a congruence relation on $(\Bbb Z,+,0,-)$?

Comment: An equivalence relation that is compatible with all the operations on the algebraic structure (in this case $(\mathbb{Z},+,0,-)$). For the operation "$+$" this means

$a_1\sim b_1 \land a_2\sim b_2 \Rightarrow a_1+a_2 \sim b_1+b_2$.

For "$-$" this means $a\sim b\Rightarrow -a\sim -b$.

For "$0$" this just means $0\sim 0$, which is trivial since $\sim$ is reflexive.

Comment: Ok. For the record, the "trivial ones" you indicated are already included in the previous case by considering $d=1$ and $d=0$ respectively.

Comment: Indeed, I haven't noticed that in the first place :)